# Why is command completion on Neovim command line ignored with vim.api.nvim_set_keymap but working fine with vim.keymap.set?

Tags: lua, neovim

In Neovim, when in command mode, you can type a couple of letters and then hit the up arrow and it will show you the command that began with the same letters earlier in your history.

When I create a map to use `<c-p>` using `vim.api`:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("x", "<c-p>", "<up>", { noremap = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("x", "<c-n>", "<down>", { noremap = true })
```

The first few letters are completely ignored and it cycles through all previous commands.

However, this works:

```lua
vim.keymap.set("c", "<c-p>", "<up>")
vim.keymap.set("c", "<c-n>", "<down>")
```

Now if I type `:e` and then `<c-p>`, it will cycle through previous commands that begin with `e`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using different modes between `nvim_set_keymap` and `vim.keymap.set`:

- `x` means that the keymap will only activate in visual mode.
- `c` means that the keymap will only activate in command mode.

Hence, your mapping via `nvim_set_keymap` is never set for the mode you actually want to use. Instead, the default mapping `Ctrl`+`p` is retained, which just cycles up through previous lines.

Changing to the mode to `c` (for command) solves the issue:

```lua
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("c", "<c-p>", "<up>", { noremap = true })
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap("c", "<c-n>", "<down>", { noremap = true })
```

All the map modes can be found using `:h map-table`:

```
         Mode  | Norm | Ins | Cmd | Vis | Sel | Opr | Term | Lang | 
Command        +------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+------+------+ 
[nore]map      | yes  |  -  |  -  | yes | yes | yes |  -   |  -   |
n[nore]map     | yes  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
[nore]map!     |  -   | yes | yes |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
i[nore]map     |  -   | yes |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
c[nore]map     |  -   |  -  | yes |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
v[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  | yes | yes |  -  |  -   |  -   |
x[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  | yes |  -  |  -  |  -   |  -   |
s[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  |  -  | yes |  -  |  -   |  -   |
o[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  | yes |  -   |  -   |
t[nore]map     |  -   |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -  | yes  |  -   |
l[nore]map     |  -   | yes | yes |  -  |  -  |  -  |  -   | yes  |
```

---

**Why the `vim.keymap.set` Lua function in Neovim?**

According the [release notes](https://neovim.io/news/2022/04), from Neovim 0.7, the Lua only `vim.keymap.set` was added as a convenience function which differs from `nvim_set_keymap` in the following ways:

- It can accept either a string or a Lua function as its 3rd argument.
- It sets noremap by default, as this is what users want 99% of the time.

Technically it is a wrapper around the API `nvim_set_keymap` intended to make mappings easier. I'd recommend using it unless you have a requirement for using the API directly.